# How to hot reload a struct from file changes

Tags: file, rust, watch, notify

I'm trying to do hot reloading when a file changes, but I'm getting this error:
expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnMut`
this closure implements `FnMut`, not `Fn`

Seems to be unhappy with the closure I'm passing to the new_immediate function from this library:

```
notify = { version = "5.0.0-pre.4", features = ["serde"] }
```

My code:

```
use announcer::messages::{load_config, save_config, Config, Message};
use notify::{
    event::ModifyKind, Error, Event, EventFn, EventKind, RecommendedWatcher, RecursiveMode, Watcher,
};
use tide::{http, Body, Response};

const CONFIG_PATH: &str = "config.json";

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> tide::Result<()> {
    let mut config = load_config(CONFIG_PATH).unwrap();

    let mut watcher: RecommendedWatcher =
        Watcher::new_immediate(|result: Result<Event, Error>| {
            let event = result.unwrap();
            
            if event.kind == EventKind::Modify(ModifyKind::Any) {
                config = load_config(CONFIG_PATH).unwrap();
            }
        })?;

    watcher.watch(CONFIG_PATH, RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;

    let mut app = tide::with_state(config);
    app.listen("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I asked in the Rust Discord beginners chat and 17cupsofcoffee said I should be using a mutex but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're spawning this watching function in another thread, and you might write to it in one thread while reading to it in another, causing a race condition. You should use a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), and `lock` it to get a guard that lets you read from it/write to it. Since `tide`'s global state also needs `Clone`, you should also wrap it in an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), a thread-safe reference-counted pointer:

```rust
use announcer::messages::{load_config, save_config, Config, Message};
use notify::{
    event::ModifyKind, Error, Event, EventFn, EventKind, RecommendedWatcher, RecursiveMode, Watcher,
};
use tide::{http, Body, Response};
// necessary imports
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

const CONFIG_PATH: &str = "config.json";

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> tide::Result<()> {
    // we store it in an Arc<Mutex<T>>
    let config = Arc::new(Mutex::new(load_config(CONFIG_PATH).unwrap()));
    let cloned_config = Arc::clone(&config);

    let mut watcher: RecommendedWatcher =
        Watcher::new_immediate(move |result: Result<Event, Error>| {
            let event = result.unwrap();
            
            if event.kind == EventKind::Modify(ModifyKind::Any) {
                // we lock the mutex to acquire a mutable guard and write to that
                match load_config(CONFIG_PATH) {
                    Ok(new_config) => *cloned_config.lock().unwrap() = new_config,
                    Err(error) => println!("Error reloading config: {:?}", error),
                }
        })?;

    watcher.watch(CONFIG_PATH, RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;
    
    let mut app = tide::with_state(config);
    app.listen("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Then, whenever you need to read from the state, you just lock the mutex:

```rust
let config_guard = req.state().lock().unwrap();
println!("{:?}", config_guard.foo);
```

For additional reference:

- [*The Rust Language: Shared-State Concurrency*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html)

Comment: Awesome, I tried this and it works if you don't save the file too often. I got the concept of Arcs though so that's great! I've created an issue in the library to hopefully figure out how to make it reliable. https://github.com/notify-rs/notify/issues/275#issue-774886587